# Read returns 0 after a few operations

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, posix

I have a TCP multithreading comunication between the client and the server. I have no ideea why the third time when I use the read function it only gives 0.

1. Client code

```
while(1)
    {
        /* citirea raspunsului dat de server
              (apel blocant pina cind serverul raspunde) */
        if (read(sd, msg, 1024) < 0) {
            perror("[client]Eroare la read() de la server.\n");
            return errno;
        }

        /* afisam mesajul primit */
        printf("[client]Mesajul primit este: %s\n", msg);
        if(strcmp(msg, "Conexiune incheiata") == 0)
            break;
        memset(mesaj,0,256);

        cin>>mesaj;

        /* trimiterea mesajului la server */
        if (write(sd, mesaj, 1024) <= 0) {
            perror("[client]Eroare la write() spre server.\n");
            return errno;
        }

    }
    /* inchidem conexiunea, am terminat */
    close (sd);
```

2. Server main code and the function where i found the problem

```
#include "ConectareServer.h"
using namespace std;
/* portul folosit */
#define PORT 2825

/* codul de eroare returnat de anumite apeluri */
extern int errno;

typedef struct thData{
    int idThread; //id-ul thread-ului tinut in evidenta de acest program
    int cl; //descriptorul intors de accept
}thData;

static void *treat(void *); /* functia executata de fiecare thread ce realizeaza comunicarea cu clientii */
void raspunde(void *);

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "EndlessLoop"
int main ()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;  // structura folosita de server
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int nr;     //mesajul primit de trimis la client
    int sd;     //descriptorul de socket
    int pid;
    pthread_t th[100];    //Identificatorii thread-urilor care se vor crea
    int i=0;


    /* crearea unui socket */
    if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server]Eroare la socket().\n");
        return errno;
    }
    /* utilizarea optiunii SO_REUSEADDR */
    int on=1;
    setsockopt(sd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&on,sizeof(on));

    /* pregatirea structurilor de date */
    bzero (&server, sizeof (server));
    bzero (&from, sizeof (from));

    /* umplem structura folosita de server */
    /* stabilirea familiei de socket-uri */
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    /* acceptam orice adresa */
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    /* utilizam un port utilizator */
    server.sin_port = htons (PORT);

    /* atasam socketul */
    if (bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server]Eroare la bind().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /* punem serverul sa asculte daca vin clienti sa se conecteze */
    if (listen (sd, 2) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server]Eroare la listen().\n");
        return errno;
    }
    /* servim in mod concurent clientii...folosind thread-uri */
    while (1)
    {
        int client;
        thData * td; //parametru functia executata de thread
        int length = sizeof (from);

        printf ("[server]Asteptam la portul %d...\n",PORT);
        fflush (stdout);

        // client= malloc(sizeof(int));
        /* acceptam un client (stare blocanta pina la realizarea conexiunii) */
        if ( (client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, reinterpret_cast<socklen_t *>(&length))) < 0)
        {
            perror ("[server]Eroare la accept().\n");
            continue;
        }

        /* s-a realizat conexiunea, se astepta mesajul */

        // int idThread; //id-ul threadului
        // int cl; //descriptorul intors de accept

        td=(struct thData*)malloc(sizeof(struct thData));
        td->idThread=i++;
        td->cl=client;
        pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &treat, td);

    }//while
};
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
static void *treat(void * arg)
{
    struct thData tdL;
    tdL= *((struct thData*)arg);
    printf ("[thread]- %d - Asteptam mesajul...\n", tdL.idThread);
    fflush (stdout);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    raspunde((struct thData*)arg);
    /* am terminat cu acest client, inchidem conexiunea */
    printf ("[Server]Inchidem conexiunea cu threadul %d\n",tdL.idThread);
    close ((intptr_t)arg);
    return(NULL);

}


void raspunde(void *arg)
{
   
    struct thData tdL;
    tdL= *((struct thData*)arg);
    ConectareServer client;
    cout<<tdL.cl;
    client.Conectare(tdL.cl);

}
```

```
void ConectareServer::Conectare(int arg) {
    fd=arg;
    cout<<fd;
    memset(mesaj_catre_client, 0, 1024);
    sprintf(mesaj_catre_client,
            "Conectare reusita, pentru a continua, trebuie sa te loghezi. Sintaxa comenzilor este urmatoarea: \n<login>, pentru a realiza logarea la server\n"
            "<quit>, pentru a inchide programul");
    write(arg, mesaj_catre_client, sizeof(mesaj_catre_client));
    VerifComanda(arg);
}
void ConectareServer::VerifComanda(int fd) {
    memset(mesaj_catre_client, 0, 1024);
    memset(mesaj_de_la_client, 0, 1024);
    read(fd, mesaj_de_la_client, sizeof(mesaj_de_la_client));
    printf("[server]Mesajul a fost receptionat...%s\n", mesaj_de_la_client);
    if(strcmp(mesaj_de_la_client, "login")==0){
        Logare client(fd);
        client.Login();
        cout<<"Intra in Logare";
    }
    if (strcmp(mesaj_de_la_client, "quit") == 0) {
        sprintf(mesaj_catre_client, "Conexiune incheiata");
        write(fd, mesaj_catre_client, sizeof(mesaj_catre_client));
    }
    if(strcmp(mesaj_de_la_client, "login") != 0 && strcmp(mesaj_de_la_client, "quit") != 0)
    {
        cout<<"Crash";
    }
}
```

And

```
void Logare::Login() {
    memset(mesaj_catre_client, 0, 256);
    char user[10];
    char parola[8];
    sprintf(mesaj_catre_client,"Introduceti user-ul: ");
    write (fd, mesaj_catre_client, sizeof(mesaj_catre_client));
    read (fd, user, sizeof (user));

    printf ("[server]Mesajul a fost receptionat...%s\n", user);

    memset(mesaj_catre_client, 0, 256);
    sprintf(mesaj_catre_client,"Introduceti parola: ");
    write (fd, mesaj_catre_client, sizeof(mesaj_catre_client));

    read (fd, parola, sizeof (parola));
    printf ("[s]Mesajul a fost receptionat...%s\n", parola);

    if(Verificare_Logare(user,parola) == 1)
    {
        // Logare reusita
        Meniu client(fd, user);
        client.MeniuAplicatie();

    }
}
```

I get the right reading for login and user but when it comes to the read of the parola it just returns 0 before i can put an input in the client window.

Comment: It might help if you can translate your comments [and messages] from Romanian into English. The reason I know they're Romanian is that I put: `parametru functia executata de thread` into Google Translate and got back: `parameter function executed by the thread`. Also, this appears to be `c++` and _not_ `c`, so you may want to remove the `c` tag.

Comment: But, at a glance, you're _not_ checking return values for a few functions (e.g. `read` and `write`). And, (e.g.) you're doing: `sprintf(mesaj_catre_client,"Introduceti parola: "); write (fd, mesaj_catre_client, sizeof(mesaj_catre_client));` But, you might be better off with: `size_t len = sprintf(mesaj_catre_client,"Introduceti parola: "); write (fd, mesaj_catre_client, len + 1);`.

Comment: There are at least two major problems: 1. You always write a whole buffer, so if the user enters "hi" you send "hi\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0[...]". 2. You assume that one write from the client becomes one read on the server. This is not true in general, and definitely not true when you write large buffers and read smaller ones. Since you appear to want a line based protocol, you should look at how to read and write lines.

Comment: Since you're doing `read(...,whatever,sizeof(whatever))`, you may need to look at the return value because the _first_ `read` may read the first message but the buffer has the initial part of the second message. (e.g.) If the sender sent _two_ messages (e.g. `hello` and `world`), the receiver may get `helloworld` as the first [and only] message because it gets 10 bytes instead of just 5.

Comment: Please use English in code comments. You probably need to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then more about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), including [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Consider using [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or some parts of [GTK](http://gtk.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code. `read()` returning 0 is the least of the observed problem. In fact it's likely only the end result of all the other problems in the shown code, and not the real cause. First major problem occurs many times, and the best example is the server code:

```
write (fd, mesaj_catre_client, sizeof(mesaj_catre_client));
```

This code is writing to the socket. This completely ignores the return code from `write()`. When writing to sockets, ***you have absolutely no guarantee whatsoever*** that everything will be written to the socket. You want to write `sizeof(mesaj_catre_client)` number of bytes here. Well, unfortunately you have no guarantee that all of these bytes will be written. `write()` can write only the first byte of `mesaj_catre_client` and return 1. Or write about half of this structure, and return the number of bytes that was actually written. Your code must check that, but your code ignores it, so you don't really know what's been written to the socket, here.

The return value of every call to `write()` ***must*** be checked and the program's logic adjusted accordingly. The usual solution is to repeat the `write()`, this time for the remaining bytes.

Same logical bug occurs when reading from sockets:

```
if (read(sd, msg, 1024) < 0) {
```

And, once more, you have absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, that this will return the entire message that the server, but maybe just the first couple of bytes from it. Even if the server managed to `write()` the entire message, the first call here may return just one byte of it, and calling it again will retrieve the rest of the message (or some additional part of it).

And the opposite is true as well. If the server sent multiple messages, and they all end up to less than 1024 bytes, guess what? You'll get them all, in one fell `read()` swoop. The shown code is not prepared to handle that, at all.

Reading and writing from sockets, properly, is much harder than it seems at first.

Final set of (potential) problems with the shown code:

```
td=(struct thData*)malloc(sizeof(struct thData));

// ...

static void *treat(void * arg)
{
    struct thData tdL;
    tdL= *((struct thData*)arg);
```

The shown code is C++ code, it uses C++ classes. Modern C++ is type safe. No modern C++ code ever needs to use `malloc` or `free`, or cast to/from a `void *`. This is only necessary here because you are using C APIs. This should be replaced with type-safe `std::thread`, and it should not be necessary to `malloc` or `new` anything.

But the fundamental problem with the shown code is that it is not prepared and is not capable of correctly handling the read/write semantics of sockets, which offer very little guarantee as to what gets read and written on each `read()` and `write()` call. You cannot make any assumptions of any kind, and you must carefully implement the proper logic for writing and reading individual bytes from sockets, and assembling them into the logic structures that were read and written. Neither `read()` nor `write()` will do that for you, it is necessary to implement all the logic yourself.